# Issue in understanding compactMap & flatMap

Tags: arrays, swift, flatmap

I have gone through from multiple tutorials that `flatMap/compactMap` is used to `flatten` an array of array but in my case it's not working or I am not understanding it properly.

```
let myArray = [["Raja","Kumar", nil,"Waqas"],["UAE","SINGAPORE","dUBAI","HONGKONG"]]
let final = myArray.compactMap{ $0 }

print("Result:\(final)")
```

**OutPut:**

```
Result:[[Optional("Raja"), Optional("Kumar"), nil, Optional("Waqas")], [Optional("UAE"), Optional("SINGAPORE"), Optional("dUBAI"), Optional("HONGKONG")]]
```

I tried removing nil from the above array but still it's not flattening my array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here in short: `compactMap` filters all `nil` values from an array, `flatMap` turns an array of arrays into a single array by pulling all values from the nested arrays into a single one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`compactMap` should be used to filter out `nil` elements from an array of `Optional`s, while `flatMap` can be used to flatten out a multi-dimensional array. However, you need to do both.

```
let final = myArray.flatMap{$0.compactMap{$0}}

print("Result:\(final)")
```

Answer (score 5):

#### `.compactMap`

...is used to produce a list without optional objects, you need to use `compactMap` on the inner array where you got `nil`s, like so:

```
let result = myArray.map { $0.compactMap { $0 } }
```

**Result:** `[["Raja", "Kumar", "Waqas"], ["UAE", "SINGAPORE", "dUBAI", "HONGKONG"]]`

---

#### `.flatmap`

...is used to flatten a collection of collections, for example

```
let result = myArray.flatMap { $0.compactMap { $0 } }
```

**Result:** `["Raja", "Kumar", "Waqas", "UAE", "SINGAPORE", "dUBAI", "HONGKONG"]`

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation

[map(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map)

> Returns an array containing the **results** of mapping the given closure over the sequence’s elements.

[compactMap(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap)

> Returns an array containing the **`non-nil` results** of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

[flatMap(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap)

> Returns an array containing the **concatenated results** of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

Each *Discussion* section contains an example.